# Comparison issue with boolean mapped as BIT(1) for MySQL and H2 2.x

Tags: h2

We are facing the following error when trying to upgrade H2 from version 1.4.200 to 2.1.214.

`Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Values of types "ROW(C1 BOOLEAN, C2 BIGINT)" and "ROW(C1 INTEGER, C2 INTEGER)" are not comparable;`

Relevant SQL part `from account this_ where (this_.admin, this_.id) >= (0, 5) order by this_.admin asc, this_.id asc limit ?`

Please note that the parameters 0 and 5 (and actually the whole `WHERE`, before the "limit" part) are being added as a String using `criteria.addQueryHint()` (I know, it is a corner case, to add paging without offset)

I've read a lot of discussions about similar issues, but none of the solutions/workarounds seem applicable to our case.

We're using H2 just for automated tests, in production we use MySQL.
`BIT` is the default column type Hibernate maps for boolean in MySQL:

`MySQLDialect` in Hibernate 5.6.10.Final has:
`registerColumnType( Types.BOOLEAN, "bit" ); // HHH-6935`

I have tried adding the following code prior to executing the statement, but it didn't help.

`Mode mode = Mode.getInstance("MySQL"); mode.numericWithBooleanComparison = true;`

I have also tried to add `registerColumnType(Types.BOOLEAN, "bit");` and `registerColumnType(Types.BOOLEAN, "bit(1)");` to a `H2CustomDialect` and use it instead of `H2Dialect`, none of them helped.

Changing column types in production for several tables, each one containing hundreds of millions of records is not something I'm considering here.

What should be my approach to this problem? I don't want to stay in version 1.4.200 forever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

New versions of H2 don't allow any comparison operations between `BOOLEAN` and numeric data types in the Regular compatibility mode without explicit casts to comparable data types.

In MySQL and some other compatibility modes you can compare `BOOLEAN` and numeric values for equality (`=`) or not equality (`<>`), but you still cannot compare them with `>`, `>=`, `<`, and `<=` operators. What exactly do you expect for something like `TRUE >= 2`? Does it mean `1 >=2` (`FALSE`) or `TRUE >= TRUE` (`TRUE`)?

Because you add `>= (0, 5)` part by yourself, you can simply add `>= (FALSE, 5)` instead for both H2 and MySQL. MySQL doesn't have boolean data type, but it knows standard `TRUE` and `FALSE` literals.